# Is there any way to use ajaxcontroltoolkit textditor in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am developing asp.net mvc5 project and now I want to use text editor in the project so I have downloaded richtexteditor from nuget to the mvc project but I do not know how to use thisin the prohect .please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Ajax Control Toolkit can not be used in ASP.NET MVC projects, only non-MVC ASP.NET projects.

Comment: Ok How to use richtexteditor in mvc 5? please help me

Comment: I think you'd better post a new answer, because the second question is out of context of the original question.